# Remove xml tags from column

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have some xml data stored in database (sqlserver) in following format:
eg. email saved as follows:

```
<![CDATA[test@test.com]]>
```

My requirement is to fetch the above data without xml tags. Is it possible in sqlserver's query or not?
if yes please give your valuable suggestions.
I need only "test@test.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
declare @S varchar(25) 
set @S = '<![CDATA[test@test.com]]>'

select cast(@S as xml).value('.', 'varchar(25)')
```

With a table it could look like this.

```
select cast(email as xml).value('.', 'varchar(25)') as email
from YourTable
```